How to Read Embedding for TensorFlow
I'm trying to create an embedding in CSV, and I hope someone can help. I'm not sure I'm going about this the right way, but I would appreciate any help. When I try to train the model, I get:
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).
Sample data looks like:
fld0,fld1,fld2,fld3,fld4,fld5,fld6,fld7,fld8,fld9,fld10,fld11,fld12,fld13,fld14,fld15,fld16,fld17,fld18,fld19,fld20,fld21,fld22,fld23,fld24,fld25,fld26,fld27,fld28,fld29,fld30,fld31,fld32,fld33,fld34,fld35,fld36,fld37,fld38,fld39,fld40,fld41,fld42,fld43,fld44,fld45,fld46,fld47,fld48,fld49,fld50,fld51,fld52,fld53,fld54,fld55,fld56,fld57,fld58,fld59,fld60,fld61,fld62,fld63,fld64,fld65,fld66,fld67,fld68,fld69,fld70,fld71,fld72,fld73,fld74,fld75,fld76,fld77,fld78,fld79,fld80,fld81,fld82,fld83,fld84,fld85,fld86,fld87,fld88,fld89,fld90,fld91,fld92,fld93,fld94,fld95,fld96,fld97,fld98,fld99,fld100,fld101,fld102,fld103,fld104,fld105,fld106,fld107,fld108,fld109,fld110,fld111,fld112,fld113,fld114,fld115,fld116,fld117,fld118,fld119,fld120,fld121,fld122,fld123,fld124,fld125,fld126,fld127,fld128,fld129,fld130,fld131,fld132,fld133
0.5713509314139188,1,1,0,0,1,0.49030538979462923,[ 0.0756 0.0756 0.1176 0.0672 0.0588 0.0756 0.0672 0.0504 0.0336 0.1008 0.0252 0.0252 0.0252 0.0672 0.0252 0.0252 0.0168 0.0084 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0084 0.0084 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0420 ],0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

I'm using pandas 2.2.3 w/ Python 3.10.13. I hunted around for the problem and found recommendations on using convert() which I've done. When I display the column, I think it looks right.
My code is:
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def convert(item):
    item = item[1:-1]    # remove `[ ]`
    item = item.strip()  # remove spaces at the end
    item = np.fromstring(item, sep=' ')  # convert string to `numpy.array`
    return item

print("TensorFlow Version: "+tf.__version__)

X_train = pd.read_csv('training.csv',converters={'fld7':convert})
y_train = pd.read_csv('training_labels.csv')
print(f"{X_train.shape=}")
print(f"{y_train.shape=}")

x_row=X_train.iloc[0]
x_val=x_row['fld7']
print(f"{type(x_row)=} {x_row=}")
print(f"{type(x_val)=} {x_val=}")

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2048, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2048, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.003),
    metrics=[
        tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
        tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
        tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall')
    ]
    )

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=25)

The output when I run my program is:
X_train.shape=(10, 134)
y_train.shape=(10, 1)
type(x_row)=<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> x_row=fld0      0.571351
fld1             1
fld2             1
fld3             0
fld4             0
            ...   
fld129           0
fld130           0
fld131           0
fld132           0
fld133           0
Name: 0, Length: 134, dtype: object
type(x_val)=<class 'numpy.ndarray'> x_val=array([0.0756, 0.0756, 0.1176, 0.0672, 0.0588, 0.0756, 0.0672, 0.0504,
       0.0336, 0.1008, 0.0252, 0.0252, 0.0252, 0.0672, 0.0252, 0.0252,
       0.0168, 0.0084, 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.0084, 0.0084, 0.    ,
       0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    ,
       0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.042 ])

2024-10-08 20:14:52.337621: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:901] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2024-10-08 20:14:52.339066: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1929] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 20723 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA A10G, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0, compute capability: 8.6
2024-10-08 20:14:52.339066: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1929] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 20723 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA A10G, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0, compute capability: 8.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/new_model/testcase.py", line 44, in <module>
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=25)
  File "/opt/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/opt/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 103, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).


The error message is quite straightforward. the value for column 'fld7' is NumPy array type.
Below is my suggestion for manipulating the problematic column into new columns.
X_train = X_train.join(  # joining new dataframe that been created with the transform of column 'fld7'
    X_train.fld7.transform(  # transforming the column array into dataframe columns with the respective value.
        {
            f'fld7_{i}':  # generating the new column name
            lambda x, j=i:  # for each of the value index save it's index for the Lambda function
            x[j] for i in range(len(X_train.fld7[0]))  # assign the array value by its index
        }
    )).drop(columns='fld7')  # dropping the array column.

Please note that I assume that all the arrays in that column have the same length (40), else you will have a different count of columns for each row.
Result:
    fld0    fld1    fld2    fld3    fld4    fld5    fld6    fld8    fld9    fld10   ... fld7_30 fld7_31 fld7_32 fld7_33 fld7_34 fld7_35 fld7_36 fld7_37 fld7_38 fld7_39
0   0.571351    1   1   0   0   1   0.490305    0   0   0   ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.042

